# tightVNC connection from python2.7 error --No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: python-2.7, tcp, vnc, vnc-server, vnc-viewer

I have installed vncdotool on my python2.7

Download and install python-2.7.5.exe from the Python Downloads website

Open up Powershell, and paste in the following:

Restart your Windows Machine

Upon Restart, go to the Twisted Downloads and get and install 32bit Twisted, Twisted-13.1.0.win32-py2.7.exe

Download and install PIL-1.1.7.win32-py2.7.exe, from PIL Downloads.

Download ez_setup.py and get_pip.py and save them to your Python/Scripts folder, C:\Python27\Scripts

Open up Powershell and type the following:

```
pip install pip --upgrade
pip install distribute
pip install setuptools --upgrade
pip install Twisted --upgrade
pip install vncdotool < -- Finally install vncdotool
```

At a Powershell prompt:

vncdo.exe --server 192.168.2.2 type "Hello World"

i tried above follow.
now i got error
like this.

```
c:\Python27\Scripts>vncdo.exe --server 192.168.2.11 type "hello world"
```

CRITICAL:root:Connection was refused by other side: 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it..

Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has not problem.
May be problem is firewall or antivirus or server will sent your set rather than ack.

Comment: i tried this using vnc client. it works well but when i am using python it give me problems.